# Can Subject Alternative Name(SAN) Certificate install on different Web Server or OS?

Tags: ssl, web-server, ssl-certificate, certificate

Let say:

```
application.house.com   apache tomcat         : physical server

email.house.com         apache tomcat         : virtual 

finance.house.com       Oracle Wallet Manager : physical server 

document.house.com      apache httpd          : physical server 

room.house.com          IIS 7 : windows       : physical server 

person.house.com        apache tomcat         : virtual 

portal.house.com        apache                : physical server
```

Assume: portal.house.com domain will be common subject name for that SAN Certificate and the rest of domains will be in Subject Alternative Name extension.

For Certificate Signing Request(CSR),I will generate a CSR at apache server using openssl included FQDN domain in SAN extension. Is it enough?

Can each domain of every server recognize this type of certificate after that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can buy one certificate and use it on unlimited number of servers. However, some servers may require you to convert the certificate and the private key into an appropriate format. You may look into documentation to find the details for each program.